# .NET Core 3.1 - Run Python 3.7 post build script in platform independent way

Tags: python, .net, python-3.x, .net-core, msbuild

**What I want to acheive**

Run Python 3.7 script on post-build in .NET Core 3.1 so it works out of the box on both Linux and Windows.

**Assumptions I make**

- Machine on which one will build project we will have at least 2 version of Python installed, i.e. 2.7 and 3.6+.
- Both Python versions are in PATH.
- I would like to avoid any manipulation such as renaming binaries or editing PATH etc. This should work out of the box, without any hacks.

**Additional problem**

To access script I use MSBuild macros such as `$(SolutionDir)`, so path script will OS-dependent because of `/` and `\`

**What I tried**

My understanding is: having Python 2.x and 3.x installed in parallel the most simple way to be sure that script will be executed using Python 3.x is to use `py -3` on Windows and `python3` on Linux. As calling `python` will effect in executing script using Python 2.x.

I tried to force MSBuild to run different post build scripts in at least 3 different ways:

(1)

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Unix' ">
    <Message>Uisng post-build scripts for Unix/Linux
      </Message>
    <Command>python3 $(SolutionDir)BuildTools\PostBuild.py -s $(SolutionDir) -p $(ProjectPath) -c $(ConfigurationName) -t $(TargetDir) -n $(ProjectName)
      </Command>
  </PostBuildEvent>
  <PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    <Message>Using post-build scripts for Windows
      </Message>
    <Command>py -3 $(SolutionDir)BuildTools/PostBuild.py -s $(SolutionDir) -p $(ProjectPath) -c $(ConfigurationName) -t $(TargetDir) -n $(ProjectName)
      </Command>
  </PostBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

(2)

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
  <Exec Command="py -3 $(SolutionDir)BuildTools\PostBuild.py -s $(SolutionDir) -p $(ProjectPath) -c $(ConfigurationName) -t $(TargetDir) -n $(ProjectName) -o $(TargetPath) -f $(TargetFileName)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Unix'">
  <Exec Command="python3 $(SolutionDir)BuildTools/PostBuild.py -s $(SolutionDir) -p $(ProjectPath) -c $(ConfigurationName) -t $(TargetDir) -n $(ProjectName) -o $(TargetPath) -f $(TargetFileName)" />
</Target>
```

(3)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  (...)
  <IsWindows Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">true</IsWindows>
  <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then using this properties for condition in (2) and (3).

But none if those works. What am I missing? Or what do I do wrongly? Maybe there's some other way of achieving the same effect?

Many thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft about declaring target in a project file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019#declare-targets-in-the-project-file

This means that since both of your post-build events are named the same, the second post-build would hide the first, meaning the only post-build that could be run is the Linux script when you are running on a Linux machine.

To make it work, change your code into something like this:

```
<Target Name="PostBuildWindows" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
```

```
<Target Name="PostBuildLinux" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Unix'">
```

You can change the name value to anything you like but make sure it explains what it is.